# Thingsboard rule chain: How to decompress telemetry?

Tags: thingsboard

I am trying to use thingsboard to allow users to request log files from devices.  When requested, the devices send the log files to my TB server as telemetry.  First, the logs are compressed with gzip and then base64 encoded. I want to have the rule chain decompress these logs and email to the requestor. I've found code to convert the base64 string to a byte array, but I haven't found a way to decompress the resulting byte array. I tried to invoke zlib using:

`var zlib = require('zlib');`

but it results in an message that *'require'* is not defined.

Any hints?   What language exactly is the TB rule node environment?

Comment: Don't think that's going to be possible in TB. You could send the byte array to an AWS Lambda function and import 'zlib' there and return the result

Comment: Instead of calling `require` you could copy content of, for example, [minified version of zlib](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js/blob/develop/bin/zlib.min.js) to *Transformation* rule node and then call this API to decompress data. This would works if zlib library doesn't depend on some OS specific API.

Comment: AFAIK RuleChains use a terrible old partial implementation of JavaScript (a Java parser / interpreter or something like that). Think IE 6/9 level JS at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We send it to S3 and then have a link to it available on the TB gui - the user can request a log file(s) on the UX and then a few minutes later can click on the logfile and it downloads to their computer/device as a zip file. Device is linux based.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  It's very helpful just to know that there isn't an easy way to do this in the TB rule chain.